# What is the signal carrier in a coaxial cable?

Tags: rf, transmission-line, coax

I'm confused about coaxial cables being called waveguides and the role of the outer shield being to cancel the waves. Is it the alternating current that carries the information (with voltage receivers on the receiving end) or is it the alternating field (with some antenna-like apparatus at the receiving end where voltage is generated by the alternating field)? In this latter case the field waves are not cancelled, after all(?)
If it's all about currents though and the EM waves are just side effects, then is the shield the return path of the current?

Comment: What resources have you found so far in your research?

Comment: I imagine it like this: The signal's AC causes EM waves which try to 'escape' radially from the condutor and the shield prevents that. Once the conductor leaves the shield, i.e. when the coax connects to an antenna, the waves finally start 'escaping' their confinement and radiate away.

Comment: @Sean Houlihane Wikipedia and questions on stackoverflow.

Comment: @JimmyB So you mean the EM waves are just side effects and it's the alternating current that is used?

Comment: "Used"? Used for what?!

Comment: Yes the shield is normally the return path for the current.

Comment: @stevie What I really meant was refer to the most complete specific diagrams etc. which you have found already. This question is too broad to be answerable for now - unless you're expecting someone to write a chapter for a textbook...

Comment: You can't really say that the current and the EM waves are "separate", as any current will *necessarily* induce an EM field. And talking about "information" is a distraction too; it carries a signal, and how you interpret that is up to you.

Comment: @JimmyB I mean if the current is used, it means the current is fed to the receiver directly (into transistors for example) and there you have the signal. Okay, my question can be reformulated as this: what is the receiver here? An antenna or a current receiving circuitry?

Comment: @pjc50 Sure they are interdependent. I just want to know if the EM wave is fed into a field effect transistor at the end or the current is fed into circuitry directly. It can be any of these two, of course, but surely it's just one of them, isn't it?

Comment: Right, that's a different question! It's not a question about the cable but about the receiving device. In which case it depends on the frequency of interest and what the "RF frontend" of the system looks like - maybe it's going directly into an amplifier, maybe it's going into an LC tuned circuit for a standard superhet tuner.

Comment: (A FET gate "looks like" a capacitor, and has to be fed with an electrical signal, you can't put an EM wave *directly* into the gate)

Comment: @pjc50 Yes, sorry for saying it's fed into the FET. Anyway, it would be the first point of contact for EM waves. I was thinking of a broadband internet line and the inner workings of my cable modem. So I guess it's approaching the highest frequencies the coax can handle. Especially because the internet provider is continuously increasing the speed. So for Ghz ranges would it be the EM waves that are...making first contact? :-) (I can see formulating this part of the question is the biggest challenge here)

Comment: @Brian Drummond: good point. Many people forget current (wherever it may be) *flows in loops* http://www.sigcon.com/Pubs/misc/whyjohnny.htm

Answer (score 2):

In coaxial cables, the RF signal travels in TEM mode both on the outside of the inner conductor and on the inside of the outer conductor(shield) if the input generator (antenna, sig gen, etc) and and the output load match the coaxial cable impedance. Waveguides have no center conductor and operate in either the TE or TM mode and have cutoff frequencies. If the coaxial cable is high quality and has a shield approaching 99% there is very little if any ingress and egress of the signal.  As the frequency goes higher, UHF and above the the Rf signal travels mostly on the outside surface of the inner conductor and on the inside surface of the outside conductor(shield). This is the so called "skin effect" where the Rf signal does not penetrate deep into the conductor. It is more pronounced as the frequency gets higher and higher. If input, cable and load are all matched the two signal paths are of opposite polarity at any finite point along the cable since RF is AC and AC current requires a return path from load to generator. The same is also true for  parallel open wire transmission lines. The coaxial cable impedance is determined by the diameter of the inside conductor, the inside diameter of the outside conductor, the distance between them and the dielectric constant of the insulating material. This is a calculator for the impedance of coaxial cable. impedance[https://www.pasternack.com/t-calculator-coax-cutoff.aspx] I have no connection to this link other than it is handy. 2010Hivoltage

Comment: At sufficient high frequencies the coax can also transmit TE and TM waves (microwaves)! This can sometimes trouble!

Answer (score 1):

I think the core of your question is addressed by pjc50's comment:

> You can't really say that the current and the EM waves are "separate", as any current will necessarily induce an EM field. And talking about "information" is a distraction too; it carries a signal, and how you interpret that is up to you.

But let me elaborate a little bit.

All classical electromagnetic phenomena are modeled by Maxwell's equations. Not just radiation through the air, and antennas, but also digital and analog circuits. But Maxwell's equations are very complicated to understand, so in many cases we reduce them to a simpler set of equations that can accurately describe some subset of phenomena.

For example, in the lumped circuit approximation, when the dimensions of a circuit are much less than the wavelength associated with any signal frequencies present in the circuit, we can use Kirchoff's Laws and the I-V characteristics of each component to model the circuit.

Transmission lines are too big for the lumped circuit approximation to hold, but still we can use simpler equations than Maxwell's to solve them. We get the [telegrapher's equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telegrapher%27s_equations) which describe the behavior of a transmission line in terms of a voltage and current, even though the electrostatic potential (aka "voltage") is only strictly correctly defined for static circuits (where there is no time variation). Despite this theoretical limitation, these equations give an adequate model of a transmission line for many purposes.

But that doesn't mean we can't also use Maxwell's equations to model a transmission line, and in fact doing so will give a "more correct" result. This would mean modeling the electric and magnetic fields in the dielectric, along with the currents in the conductors (but not ever refer to a "voltage" in either of the conductors).

When people say that the signal in a coaxial cable is actually in the fields in the dielectric, they are basically referring to this --- that Maxwell's equations are the more fundamental model, and the telegrapher's equations are a simplification that often gets us to an adequate solution with less effort, but aren't as well grounded in theory.

Comment: I hope I'm not getting something fundamentally wrong here. I thought we had two things in a coax cable simultaneously: electrons moving in the inner conductor (or on its surface because of the skin effect) and resulting standing EM waves that are perpendicular to the inner conductor and are confined to the whole cable because of the shield. Than the receiver would have two choices: either receive the electrons of the inner conductor directly or sense the standing EM waves (which would then induce current in the circuitry).

Comment: @stevie, 1. You will have moving electrons on both conductors, not just the inner conductor. 2. Whether you look at voltages and currents, or waves, they're just two ways to think about the same physical phenomenom.

Comment: If you need to think of your receiver as having an antenna to capture the waves in the cable, consider that the whole inner conductor for the whole length of the cable can act as that antenna.

Comment: Okay, I'm just obsessed about the receiver, I don't know why :-) How would it be practical for frequencies required to transmit broadband internet to be received? Via a FET (for EM waves) or a traditional transistor (for flowing electrons)? I guess it's just one of them in most commercial cable modems, or is it random? Somehow I suspect it's a traditional transistor then. In the end, the circuit uses currents, so why the extra step to have it induced by an EM wave.

Comment: As always, whenever you think about electrons for current, your intuitions will mislead you. Especially if you're waiting for an electron from one end to arrive at the other.

Comment: @pjc50 I know that about electrons. Okay, then I'll try to be precise. Whatever the coax cable runs into at the end can receive the signal in (at least) the following two ways: the inner conductor is connected to the base of a transistor and the alternating current of the inner conductor will control the current from emitter to collector. Or: the coax cable terminates near a field effect transistor and the current between the FET transistor's emitter and collector will vary according to the varying EM field.

Comment: I think in what you're discussing, *either* the coax is irrelevant and you're discussing the difference in principle of operation between FET and BJT for AC signals, *or* you've misunderstood the FET. If the reciever has a FET input, the cable will terminate *at* the transistor - that is, the cable will be electrically connected all the way to the gate silicon. Not "near" it.

Comment: "current between the FET transistor's emitter and collector will vary according to the varying EM field" is mostly correct - it's just the E field that's relevant.

Comment: .. and *only* the piece of E field that applies across the gate and the source+substrate region.

Comment: @pjc50 Alright so I guess there is only a minor difference between receiving a changing field and an AC in terms of the input element. "If the receiver has a FET input, the cable will terminate at the transistor - that is, the cable will be electrically connected all the way to the gate silicon. " I thought FETs were affected by the changing field which has a range so I thought the cable does not have to make contact with the gate silicon. If it has to make contact it seems like an ordinary transistor.

Comment: FETs do operate by electrical field, but only within the device, not from outside. Think about it - computer processors are made out of FETs; if there was any significant effect from nearby it wouldn't be possible to pack them into such a small space.

Answer (score 0):

To determine where a signal is carried, you can evaluate the so called [Poynting vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poynting_vector) (**S**). It represents the *energy flux density* at a point. It is calculated from the **E** and **B** fields:

$$ \bar S = {1 \over \mu_0} \bar E \times \bar B $$

If you integrate this vector over some area, you will know how much energy flows through that area.

These calculations have been done for coax; [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poynting_vector) says:

> Electrical energy delivered to the load is flowing entirely through
>   the dielectric between the conductors. Very little energy flows in the
>   conductors themselves, since the electric field strength is nearly
>   zero.

Answer (score 0):

I say the signal travels outside of the core wire - but inside the dialectic insulation.As dialectic insulation is resistance to penetration.Once outside the inner dialectic insulation its a different situation >